# How is the Point2D "angle" method to be understood?

Tags: javafx, geometry

I thought I'd use the Point2D class for calculating e. g. the angle betwen 2 points instead of creating a utility method. It turned out, it's not usable at all.

Code example:

```
Point2D p1;
Point2D p2;

p1 = new Point2D(0, 0);
p2 = new Point2D(10, 10);

System.out.println( "Point2D: " + p1.angle(p2));
System.out.println( "Correct: " + Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(p2.getY() - p1.getY(),  p2.getX() - p1.getX())));

p1 = new Point2D(1, 1);
p2 = new Point2D(10, 10);

System.out.println( "Point2D: " + p1.angle(p2));
System.out.println( "Correct: " + Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(p2.getY() - p1.getY(),  p2.getX() - p1.getX())));
```

which results in

```
Point2D: NaN
Correct: 45.0
Point2D: 0.0
Correct: 45.0
```

What's the point in using Point2D? And is there an alternative in JavaFX that works as expected, i. e. calculate the angle between 2 points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The angle function returns the angle between the two vectors. For example if one vector was a unit vector pointing left and the other was a unit vector pointing up then the angle would be 90 degrees.

In the first case, the first vector (0, 0) does not have an angle, so the result is NaN. In the second case, both vectors have an angle of 45 degrees, so the angle between them is zero.

To calculate the angle of the difference between the two vectors with respect to the horizontal axis, as you seem to be trying to do, subtract one from the other and find the angle between it and the horizontal unit vector, e.g:

```
Point2D p1;
Point2D p2;
Point2D p3;
Point2D p4;

p1 = new Point2D(1, 1);
p2 = new Point2D(10, 10);

p3 = p2.subtract(p1);
p4 = new Point2D(1, 0);

System.out.println( "Point2D: " + p4.angle(p3));
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it common to use it this way, i. e. a vector in a point class? Personally if I'd use a point, i'd expect a point calculation, not something with a vector. And if I'd do something with vectors, I'd use a vector class. This Point2D class and its methods look like very bad naming.

Comment: You're welcome, I agree it's confusing. I'm not aware of any other point class that does it like this, I'm not sure how common it is. In some classes e.g. the Android Point and PointF classes there aren't any geometric calculation functions at all.

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation, Point2D.angle returns the angle between two *vectors* - thus, the points are interpreted as the endpoints of two vectors (whose origins are both at (0,0)). That's why using .angle on (0,0) returns NaN.

If you want the angle between two points, you can use (in pseudocode)

```
(1,0).angle(p2-p1)
```